# In compound words, do we use архаико- or архаическо-?

Tags: словоупотребление

In compound words do we use архаико- or архаическо- ?

For example, should we say архаико-мифологический or архаическо-мифологический?

Which one sounds better for a native speaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use **архаико-мифологический**

See examples

**Архаико-мифологические** (шаманские) модели в творчестве А. Ахматовой Текст научной статьи.

В обобщающей части работы Р.Барта - статье "Миф сегодня" предлагается и объяснение, и метод противостояния современному мифологизированию - создание новейшего искусственного мифа, конструирование условного, третьего уровня мифологии, если под первым понимать **архаико-традиционную**, под вторым - "новую".

Башня в данном случае функционирует как **архаико-мифологический** символ ...

It is also fixed in орфографический словарь.

https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-4249.htm

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: *Объяснение* или *пример* использования?